# Python String-Iteration/Manipulation Speed-Strategy

Tags: python, string, algorithm, performance, sorting

Imagine you want to manipulate a string "abcdefgh" via using an algorithm to change the string to "fbcheagd". Which strategy below would allow the program to finish quicker, or would they both finish with a tie?

Program 1:

```
msg,out,key = 'abcdefgh',str(),[5,1,2,7,4,0,6,3]
for i in key:
     out += msg[i]
msg = out
print(msg)
```

Program 2:

```
msg,out = 'abcdefgh',str()
key = {'a':'f','b':'b','c':'c','d':'h','e':'e','f':'a','g':'g','h':'d'}
for i in msg:
     out += key[i]
msg = out
print(msg)
```

Comment: Neither. Both would be slow, because string concatenation is O(n) and wasteful. Append to a list, and call `''.join` at the end.

Comment: Even better - use `str.translate` if you have a dict as you do in the second case.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: As a CPython implementation detail, it does in-place mutation of the string; it has to `realloc` each time (`str` doesn't maintain a capacity separate from the length), but in practice many of the `realloc`s don't have to move the memory (they just take more of the slack space), so it's close to an amortized `O(n)`. Not that you should rely on that; it only applies to CPython, and only to the `str` type (not to `unicode` on Py2 or `bytes` on Py3). `''.join` is portable and faster asymptotically.

Comment: As for the actual question, I'm a little unclear on what the point of the comparison is. One of these is doing an indexed shuffle, the other is performing a character translation. While both get the same effect in this case, it's doesn't translate to different inputs; character translation can't replicate arbitrary shuffles if the input has repeated characters for instance, but the translation table doesn't necessarily grow in line with the input size, while shuffles must increase the index `list` size with the input size. This boils down to asking "Which is faster, orange or cats?"

Comment: After all, if we're ignoring the completely different spheres each algorithm applies to, we could just say `out = "fbcheagd"` wins and skip loops (or even looking at the input string) entirely.

Answer (score 0):

May be we can try using python builtins and a one liner.

```
In [1]: msg='abcdefgh'

In [2]: key=[5,1,2,7,4,0,6,3]

In [3]: ''.join(zip(*sorted(zip(list(msg), key), key=lambda item:item[1]))[0])
Out[3]: 'fbcheagd'
```

Not a big fan since oneliner's when combined like this affects readability, but it works.

Comment: While fun and tricksy, this is actually slower than the equivalent approach number 1 (both theoretically and practically). The big-O is `O(n log n)` (thanks to the general purpose sorting) rather than `O(n)`, and in local tests, it takes 3-4x longer to run (even after removing wasteful stuff like wrapping `msg` in `list()`, which wastes time for no reason), even though the input is quite small. It's also non-portable (needs tweaks to work on Py3, where `zip` returns an iterator, not a `list`). `''.join([msg[i] for i in key])` is faster and more succinct.

Comment: I do agree with you 100%. Just thought of a different algorithm which struck me then.